# angularjs jasmine tests: Variable vm not found

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

New to angular and Jasmine tests in angular. So I am writing a sample unit test to test a length of an array upon initialization in my controller. I expect the array to be of length 0. However, not sure what I am missing, the test output says that it cannot find the variable `vm` I am using to refer to the array. Here is my test:

```
(function(){
'use strict';
describe('Testing UploadedReleasesController', function() {

    beforeEach(module('app.uploadedReleases'));

    describe('Testing uploaded releases controller', function(){
        var vm, controller;

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
            vm = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('UploadedReleasesController', {$scope:vm});
        }));
    });

    describe('album length', function(){
        it('it should test album length', function () {
            expect(vm.albums).toBeDefined();
            expect(vm.albums.length).toBe(0);
        });
    });

  });

})();
```

Output: `Testing UploadedReleasesController album length it should test album length FAILED
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: vm`
Any suggestions ?

**EDIT
After other responses, I modified my .spec file and the error of vm not being able to find goes away. But now I have a different error. Here is the updated code:**

```
(function(){
'use strict';
describe('Testing UploadedReleasesController', function() {
    var scope, controller;
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('UploadedReleasesController', {$scope:scope});
    }));
    beforeEach(module('app.uploadedReleases'));

    describe('album length', function(){
        it('it should test album length', function () {
            //expect(vm.albums).toBeDefined();
            expect(scope.albums.length).toBe(0);
        });
    });


   });

})();

Error:  `PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Testing UploadedReleasesController true Should be true FAILED
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'UploadedReleasesController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/ng/areq?p0=UploadedReleasesController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
undefined
    at assertArg (/Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1590)
    at assertArgFn (/Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1601)
    at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8493
    at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1916
    at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/src/app/uploadedReleases/uploaded-releases.controller.spec.js:10
    at invoke (/Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4219)
    at workFn (/Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2475)
Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!`
```

**ANOTHER EDIT: Added Oscar's solution which makes the previous error go away. Now I have another problem. HEre is my actual controller definition:**

```
(function (){

angular.module('app.uploadedReleases')
        .controller('UploadedReleasesController', UploadedReleasesController)
        .controller('ModalController', ModalController);

var ACTION = {
    CANCEL: 0,
    SAVE: 1,
    DELETE: 2,
    SUBMIT: 3
};

UploadedReleasesController.$inject = ['$log', '$scope', '$modal', 'ReleaseService', 'TrackService', 'APP_CONFIG'];
function UploadedReleasesController ($log, $scope, $modal, releaseService, trackService, APP_CONFIG){
```

So ModalController is not there in my spec file. Is that why I get the following error ?

```
`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal <- UploadedReleasesController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20UploadedReleasesController
    at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4031
    at getService (/Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4178)
    at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4036
    at getService (/Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4178)
    at invoke (/Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4210)
    at instantiate (/Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4227)
    at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8524
    at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1916
    at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/src/app/uploadedReleases/uploaded-releases.controller.spec.js:12
    at invoke (/Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4219)
    at workFn (/Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2475)
undefined
Expected undefined to be defined.
    at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/src/app/uploadedReleases/uploaded-releases.controller.spec.js:22
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'vm.albums.length')
    at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/src/app/uploa`
```

Is so, how do I resolve it ?

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `vm` earlier in the *outer scope*:

```
(function(){
'use strict';
describe('Testing UploadedReleasesController', function() {
    var vm, controller;

    beforeEach(module('app.uploadedReleases'));

    describe('Testing uploaded releases controller', function(){
        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
            vm = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('UploadedReleasesController', {$scope:vm});
        }));
    });

    describe('album length', function(){
        it('it should test album length', function () {
            expect(vm.albums).toBeDefined();
            expect(vm.albums.length).toBe(0);
        });
    });

  });

})();
```

Comment: Thanks. This gets rid of the variable vm not found error. But now I get another problem:
`Testing UploadedReleasesController album length it should test album length FAILED
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'vm.albums')
     at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/src/app/uploadedReleases/uploaded-releases.controller.spec.js:40`

Comment: You'll need to move the `beforeEach(inject...` to the top-most `describe`. That way, for each `it` test, `vm` and `controller` will be set-up

Comment: @OscarGonzalez: No luck. Tried that. Let me modify my original post in an edit section and paste the error there

Comment: @noobcoder, alternatively, move the 'album length' suite inside the 'Testing uploaded releases controller' .

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're defining `vm`in the first describe() function, and you're using it in the second one. So it's indeed undefines. Variables are scoped to their enclosing functions.

Also, you shouldn't name a variable of type "Scope" `vm`. `vm` is typically used to refer to the current controller, not to its scope. Use... $scope.

Comment: Did that. Removed the vm declaration outside and the error disappeared. Now I get a different error:  `Testing UploadedReleasesController album length it should test album length FAILED TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'vm.albums') at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/src/app/uploadedReleases/up‌​loaded-releases.controller.spec.js:40` which points to the expect(vm.albums)... calls

Comment: I have no idea of the new code of the test, so it's hard to help. But why do you still use vm in the test if you've completely removed its declaration. That doesn't make much sense to me. Edit your question, and add the new, updated code.

Comment: You're trying to create your controller before loading the module containing it. Move the `beforeEach(module('app.uploadedReleases'));` line before the first beforeEach (and make sure that module indeed contains that controller)

Comment: Thanks. I  have a different issue now. I added another update to the post. Your feedback is really helpul

Comment: Yu-our controller depends on the $modal service, and this service is not in the 'app.uploadedReleases' module that you loaded, nor in any of its module dependencies. So you neeed to add the module containing $modal to the dependencies of  'app.uploadedReleases', or you need to explicitly load it in your test: `beforeEach(module('app.uploadedReleases', 'ui.bootstrap'));`

Answer (score 1):

Move the `beforeEach(inject....` directly inside `describe('Testing UploadedReleasesController'` and instantiate the variables: `var vm, controller;`

```
describe('Testing UploadedReleasesController', function() {
    var vm, controller;
    beforeEach(inject(....
```

The before each in the 'root' suite (Testing UploadedReleasesController) will be run for each test in the the inner suites.  The inner suites will also have the vm, and controller variables availalbe.  Additionally, I would create an `afterEach` function that resets the variables to `undefined`.

Update:
Move the 'album length' suite inside 'Testing uploaded releases controller':

```
(function(){
'use strict';
describe('Testing UploadedReleasesController', function() {

    beforeEach(module('app.uploadedReleases'));

    describe('Testing uploaded releases controller', function(){
        var vm, controller;

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
            vm = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('UploadedReleasesController', {$scope:vm});
        }));

        afterEach(function() {
            vm = undefined;
            controller = undefined;
        });

        describe('album length', function(){
            it('it should test album length', function () {
                expect(vm.albums).toBeDefined();
                expect(vm.albums.length).toBe(0);
            });
        });
    });

  });

})();
```

Comment: I have a different issue. My controller has another controller associated with it like this:
`(function (){

 angular.module('app.uploadedReleases')
   .controller('UploadedReleasesController', UploadedReleasesController)
   .controller('ModalController', ModalController);
`

And the modalcontroller is not there in my spec file. Is that why I may get the following error:
` Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal <- UploadedReleasesController
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20UploadedReleasesController
`

Comment: hmmm, where do you get `$modal` from? Is it a 3rd party library? If so, make sure you add the library as a dependency in your angular.module

Comment: so I have a $modal in my main controller as my updated post suggests. It should be an angular library. Regardless, should I add it to my spec as a dependency ? if so, how ?

Comment: Take a look at the 'requires' param of angular.module: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Comment: You'll need to do something like: `angular.module('myApp', ['myThirdPartyLib'];`  When angular instantiates your app, it will let you inject services from myThirdPartyLib.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108675/discussion-between-noobcoder-and-oscar-gonzalez).

Answer (score 1):

Your two inner describe functions are at the same level as one another. The vm variable isn't in scope for the second one.

Either nest the second one inside the first. That's what I think you want. Something like this:

```
describe('Testing uploaded releases controller', function(){
        var vm, controller;

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
            vm = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('UploadedReleasesController', {$scope:vm});
        }));
        describe('album length', function(){
            it('it should test album length', function () {
                expect(vm.albums).toBeDefined();
                expect(vm.albums.length).toBe(0);
            });
        });
    });
```

Or pull the vm variable declaration outside of the first ("'Testing uploaded...")  into the top level describe.

Comment: Did that. Removed the vm declaration outside and the error disappeared. Now I get a different error:
` Testing UploadedReleasesController album length it should test album length FAILED
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'vm.albums')
     at /Users/rgoti/ingestion/external-ingestion/app/public/src/app/uploadedReleases/uploaded-releases.controller.spec.js:40` which points to the `expect(vm.albums)...` calls

Comment: Create a new question. It has to do with the way you are creating you $rootScope.

Comment: Created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511224/angularjs-jasmine-test-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object